# can we use a number as text node in XML file?

Tags: xml

can we use a number as text node in XML file?
for example

```
<2>
 <abi>Zen</abi>
</2>
```

it is giving the error as follows

Comment: The text node in that XML is "Zen".  What you really want to know is if you can use a number as an element name.

Answer (score 18):

XML elements must follow these naming rules:

```
* Names can contain letters, numbers, and other characters
* Names cannot start with a number or punctuation character
* Names cannot start with the letters xml (or XML, or Xml, etc)
* Names cannot contain spaces
```

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_elements.asp

Answer (score 1):

read the [xml spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#syntax):

> The ampersand character (&) and the
>   left angle bracket (<) MUST NOT appear
>   in their literal form, except when
>   used as markup delimiters, or within a
>   comment, a processing instruction, or
>   a CDATA section. If they are needed
>   elsewhere, they MUST be escaped using
>   either numeric character references or
>   the strings " &amp;  " and " &lt;  "
>   respectively. The right angle bracket
>   (>) may be represented using the
>   string " &gt;  ", and MUST, for
>   compatibility, be escaped using either
>   " &gt;  " or a character reference
>   when it appears in the string " ]]>  "
>   in content, when that string is not
>   marking the end of a CDATA section.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

You could use something like this, though

```
<element2>
  <abi>Zen</abi>
</element2>
```

But this would make for a really ugly XML schema, where you would ultimately be limited to a maximum number of elements.

I think you should go with something like this:

```
<element number="2">
  <abi>Zen</abi>
</element>
```

Answer (score 0):

**No You Cant Use**

XML Naming Rules

XML elements must follow these naming rules:

```
1. Names can contain letters, numbers, and other characters
2. **Names cannot start with a number or punctuation character**
3. Names cannot start with the letters xml (or XML, or Xml, etc)
4. Names cannot contain spaces
```

Any name can be used, no words are reserved.

**according to 2nd rule you cant use a number as text node in XML file, because its mean is the tag is started with a number**

[for more detail](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_elements.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Actually it can be done - you must to replace first number character in XML tag with it's [unicode representation](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/TestSuite/results/4/XEP/symbol.pdf), where:

- 0 = x0030
- 1 = x0031
- 2 = x0032
- 3 = x0033
- 4 = x0034
- 5 = x0035
- 6 = x0036
- 7 = x0037
- 8 = x0038
- 9 = x0039

For example node `<111222></111222>` can be defined as:

```
<_x0031_11222>
</_x0031_11222>
```

Java Content Repository - Apache Jackrabbit project handles node names this way. It's not beautiful, but it answers the question.