# How does .value works when the nodes have numbers in XML type

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm trying to access a node defined with numbers instead of text on a SQL server XML data type.

Why does this statement works

```
DECLARE @myDoc xml  
DECLARE @ProdID int  
SET @myDoc = '<Root>23</Root>'  

SET @ProdID =  @myDoc.value('(/Root)[1]', 'int' )  
SELECT @ProdID
```

But this one doesn't

```
DECLARE @myDoc xml  
DECLARE @ProdID int  
SET @myDoc = '<1>23</1>'  
SET @ProdID =  @myDoc.value('(/1)[1]', 'int' )
```

Comment: The second one is not even proper XML [can we use a number as text node in XML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/688635/5070879)

Comment: You should be getting an error _XML parsing: line 1, character 2, illegal qualified name character_ because `<1>` is invalid node name.

Answer (score 0):

I changed line 3:

```
DECLARE @myDoc xml  
DECLARE @ProdID int  
SET @myDoc = CAST('<Root>23</Root>' AS XML)

SET @ProdID =  @myDoc.value('(/Root)[1]', 'int' )  
SELECT @ProdID
```